# Solution to BREACH vulnerability?

Tags: security, ssl

I just recently readed this doc http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/987798
And my question is, why just don't add some random various length HTTP headers like

```
HTTP 200 OK
Cache-Control:public, max-age=60
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:11669
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
asdfnak4r9q38:asdbf2984rqf // Header with random name and random value with various length
```

And also we can add some random data in html head section.

Why am I wrong? And why this solution might not work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the length of your random headers is uniformly distributed, then you're just adding noise that increases the number of requests necessary to be sure of a guess without actually mitigating the attack.

If each guess is replayed enough times to even out the entropy introduced by your random length header, the correct guesses will still be, on average, shorter than the incorrect guesses.

As with the CRIME and TIME attacks, the fix is still to disable HTTP compression.

Comment: Right, but does that mean that injecting 512 to 1024 random kbytes will make BREACH too expensive to do? How can I calculate how much requests I need?

Comment: @VladislavMiller Let's put this in context.  RC4 is widely considered a broken cipher because the first 256 bits can be predicted with high probability after observing **several million** requests. In order to make this attack too expensive to be viable, you would be incurring a greater expense on your side than you would by simply disabling compression.